# Arranging files into folders with python or bash?

Tags: python, bash, sorting

So I have a bunch of files I want to sort into folders. The nameing scheme is as follows:

```
text_1_text_-66_text_.mrc
text_1_text_-63_text_.mrc
text_1_text_-60_text_.mrc
text_1_text_-57_text_.mrc
text_2_text_-66_text.mrc
text_2_text_-63_text.mrc
text_2_text_-60_text.mrc
```

and so on (the actual number of files is plus to minus 66 so text_1 has a lot more for example). I want to sort by the first number (so the 1 in text_1_...) I have a script that I used to previously sort files:

```
import os
import shutil

n = 1

while (n < 500):
    if os.path.isfile('Stack_%d.txt' % (n)): 
        directory = 'Stack_%d' % (n)
        os.makedirs(directory)
        shutil.move('Stack_%d.txt' % (n), 'stack_%d' % (n))
        shutil.move('Stack_%d_shifts.txt' % (n), 'stack_%d' % (n))
        shutil.move('Stack_%d.mrc' % (n), 'stack_%d' % (n))
        shutil.move('Stack_%d.rawtlt' % (n), 'stack_%d' % (n))
    else:
        n = n+1
```

This is a bit crude but worked fine to sort those files. In an ideal world I would like to just know a command similar to * in bash that means I can just use string substitution for the beginning of each and then * the rest of the quote.

Sorry I am pretty new to programming and all my use cases seem to be small scripts so getting there slowly.

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html

Answer (score 0):

you want the `glob` module https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html

```
import glob
glob.glob('text_1_text_*')
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you also ask for a bash solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

for FILE in *.mrc
do
  NUM=$(echo $FILE | cut -d'_' -f 2)
  mkdir -p Stack_$NUM
  mv $FILE Stack_$NUM
done
```